# How to calculate $\int_{0}^e\left(\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt[x]{x}\right)\,{\rm d}x $

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

I need to evaluate $$\int_{0}^e\left(\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt[x]{x}\right)\,{\rm d}x$$ How would you solve this? What I know is that $\sqrt[x]{x}$ is greatest when $x=e$. That means that $\lim\limits_{x\to e} \frac{d}{dx}\sqrt[x]{x}=0$. From this I don't know where to go for my next steps. A proof would also be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: *Hint:* Fundamental Theorem of Calculus!

Comment: note : what you say about the derivative is wrong. this only works if the extremum is attained in the the *open* interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Simon suggested
$$\int\frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt[x]{x})dx=\sqrt[x]{x}$$
by fundamental theorem of calculus. 
Thus, your problem ends up just being
$$\int_0^e\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt[x]{x}dx=\sqrt[x]{x}|_0^e=\sqrt[e]{e}$$

Comment: Technically this is an improper integral, so we should have
$$\lim_{M \to 0} \int_M^e \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \sqrt[x]{x} \; \mathrm{d}x = \lim_{M \to 0} \left(\sqrt[e]{e} - \sqrt[M]{M}\right) = \sqrt[e]{e}.$$

Comment: That's true, but most people tend to omit the limits when integrating.